# EFCore - How to have multiple navigation properties to the same type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My model contains the classes Post and PostHistory, where Post has a one-to-many relationship with PostHistory.

```
class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public PostVersion CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public PostVersion OriginalVersion { get; set; }
    public IList<PostVersion> History { get; set; }
}

class PostVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

The History property contains a list of all PostVersions related to that Post. The CurrentVersion and PreviousVersion properties both reference a perticlar version in that post history (most likley the most recent version and the first version).

My problem is that EF Core struggles to understand the relationship due to the CurrentVersion and OriginalVersion navigation properties. When I try to create a migration, I get this error message:

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Post.CurrentVersion' of type 'PostVersion'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

After that I tried to use the Fluent API to create the relationships manually.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasMany(x => x.History)
        .WithOne(x => x.Post);
    builder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasOne(x => x.CurrentVersion)
        .WithOne(x => x.Post);
    builder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasOne(x => x.OriginalVersion)
        .WithOne(x => x.Post);
}
```

But created a different error:

```
Cannot create a relationship between 'PostVersion.Post' and 'Post.CurrentVersion', because there already is a relationship between 'Post.History' and 'PostVersion.Post'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.
```

Is it possible to create this kind of relationship in EF Core code-first?

Comment: What is the correct way?

Comment: Could you jsut give me a general pointer about what part of the design is wrong please?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Are you insane asking for remote access?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit**
I did some changes, you cannot reference same property in multiple relationships. Therefore i had to use foreign keys for mappings. *PostVersion* has only one *Post* reference as you required.

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid CurrentVersionId { get; set; }
    public PostVersion CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public Guid OriginalVersionId { get; set; }
    public PostVersion OriginalVersion { get; set; }
    public IList<PostVersion> History { get; set; }
}

public class PostVersion
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PostId { get; set; }

    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasOne(x => x.CurrentVersion)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Post>(p => p.CurrentVersionId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasOne(x => x.OriginalVersion)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Post>(p => p.OriginalVersionId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasMany(x => x.History)
    .WithOne(p => p.Post)
    .HasForeignKey(pv => pv.PostId);
```

---

**Original**
You need to specify additional property for that second relationship

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public PostVersion CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public PostVersion OriginalVersion { get; set; }
    public IList<PostVersion> History { get; set; }
}

public class PostVersion
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public Post SecondPost { get; set; }
    public Post ThirdPost { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}


 modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(x => x.CurrentVersion)
            .WithOne(x => x.Post);
 modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(x => x.OriginalVersion)
            .WithOne(x => x.SecondPost);
 modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasMany(x => x.History)
            .WithOne(x => x.ThirdPost);
```

Comment: PostVersion should only reference a single Post though.

Comment: i had time to look into it more today and retested - check my edit

Comment: I was able to create migration after following your answer, but I still had trouble updating the database. I had to explicitly set the `OnDelete` behavior for each of these relationships before I could update it, and even then, it failed to create the tables for Post and PostVersion. I have no idea if that's a separate issue or not though, and since you did fix the issue that I originally had, I'm happy to make this the accepted answer. I've since changed my model to avoid this nasty relationships problem anyway, so I'm not to concerned with going any further on this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can specify onDelete behaviour in fluent definition _.WillCascadeOnDelete(false/ true);_